# Reading the second excel tabs from multiple Excel workbooks in R

Tags: r, readxl

I have troubles with reading data stored in the 2nd tab of multiple Excel spreadsheets which are stored locally. I succeeded to read all the data from the first tab of these spreadsheets using the syntax:

```
library(readxl)
filenames2017 <-list.files(pattern = "*.xls")
final2017.df <- do.call("rbind", lapply(filenames2017, read_excel))
```

However, I could not find any solution for importing data from other specific tabs than the first tab.

Answer (score 2):

`read_excel` has a `sheet` argument where you can specify the name or number of the sheet:

```
read_excel("example.xlsx", sheet = 2)
read_excel("example.xlsx", sheet = "some_sheet")
```

So you can use this to read the second sheet. `readxl::excel_sheets` will return a list of sheets if you don't know in advance how many there are.

You can pass the `sheet` argument into `read_excel` inside your `lapply` by adding it as another argument, like:

```
lapply(filenames2017, read_excel, sheet = "the_sheet")
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but this does not solve my problem. I know how to read a specific tab of an Excel workbook, but I did not manage to import data from a specific tab (other than the first) of multiple workbooks.

Comment: `lapply` is in this format: `lapply(.x, .f, ...)` - `.x` is the list and `.f` is the function, you know that. `...` is extra arguments to `.f`. So you can put `sheet = 'thesheet'` as the third argument to `lapply` and it will be passed on to your function. I will clarify that in my answer, thanks.